# ListView images preloading im ImageView without delay (using Picasso or other libs)

Tags: android, listview, picasso, image-loading

I have the problem with image loading in listview. I'm using Picasso to load pictures from network into my imageViews in each row. When I'm scrolling first time there always white background before image loaded in its place. Even if I scroll very slow or even stop scrolling before new item is showing, there still white background showing before the image is loaded. Even if these pictures wasn't taken from the network, but already from cache (yellow indicator). But when these pictures already in memory (green indicator) pictures don't loading each time when scrolling, they already loaded into imageView, so I don't have this white background (or it may appear on fast scrolling, but it's ok).

This how I use Picasso in my adapter:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).fit().centerCrop().into(imageView);
```

I know this is complicated topic and we can have OOM, but there should be some variants, as I can see it implemented in popular social networks, so I guess it possible.

P.S. `fetch()` doesn't helped me in this case, changing `fit()` with harcoded `resize(200, 200)` method also doesn't helped.

Please write your thoughts without silent minusing this post. Thanks!

Comment: hi , I am having the same problem,how did you fix it?

Comment: unfortunately I didn't fix it. still using picasso...

Answer (score 1):

```
Picasso.with("Pass Context") //
            .load("Pass URL") //
            .transform(new RoundedTransformation(5, 0))
            .placeholder(R.drawable.*) //
            .error(R.drawable.*) //
            .fit() //
            .tag(mcontext) //
            .into("Your ImageView");
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but this doesn't help. Guess there should be some tricks with adapter to preload images in imageView before the item appears on the screen.

Comment: Use .placeholde() which is load the preload images.

Comment: You didn't understand. I don't want to change placeholder from white color to another or image or something like that. I need already loaded images in imageViews on slow scrolling, like it happens when the image has been already shown in the list. Then on scrolling it's loading images without showing placeholders.